# Re-order divs in a specific order based on their text content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Due to limitations in a Wordpress plugin I am using I am attempting to sort a stylised dropdown in a specific order. Is there a way to target these divs with jQuery and order them in the order below?

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="manager">
    <div class="dd__list dd__openTobottom" style="max-height: 160px;">
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Souness</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Smith</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Advocaat</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">McLeish</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to sort it in a pre-determined order such as this:

1. Smith
2. Advocaat
3. Souness
4. McLeish

I appreciate this should be done earlier, ideally by PHP or similar but my hands are tied with the plugin I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can't change the html use css

```css
.dd__list{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction:column;
}
.dd__list div:nth-child(1):not(.dd__option){
   color:red;
   order: 3;
}
.dd__list div:nth-child(2):not(.dd__option){
   color:green;
   order: 1;
}
.dd__list div:nth-child(3):not(.dd__option){
   color:orange;
   order: 2;
}
.dd__list div:nth-child(4):not(.dd__option){
   color:olive;
   order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="manager">
    <div class="dd__list dd__openTobottom" style="max-height: 160px;">
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Souness</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Smith</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Advocaat</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">McLeish</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`:not()`since all your containers are `div` you can't just use `:nth-child`

Comment: @jilykate I did not see your answer I was writing mine,SORRY

Answer (score 0):

you say itś predetermined, so i would try something like this:

```
var arr = [ 'Smith', 'Advocaat', 'Souness', 'McLeish'];
$('.dd__openTobottom').html()
$.each( arr, function( index, value ){
    $('.dd__openTobottom').append('<div><div class="dd_option">'+value+'</div></div>')
});
```

Note: In this example the dropdown is selected by a general class and may has impact to other dropdowns, you should find a unique selector for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = ['Smith', 'Advocaat', 'Souness', 'McLeish'];
  $('.dd__openTobottom').html("");
  $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    $('.dd__openTobottom').append('<div><div class="dd_option">' + value + '</div>')
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2085/

First get the array of the names. Empty the dropdown. Iterate over the list and append the new element to the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you can try with css order: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp
the browser support infomation:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a map of the predetermined order you want, then you just sort the items by the text the contain, and reinsert them into the DOM in that order.

This keeps associated events and data, and does not simply replace the elements with new HTML

```js
var map = ['Smith', 'Advocaat', 'Souness', 'McLeish'];

$('.dd__list > div').sort(function(a,b) {
    var aText = $(a).text().trim();
    var bText = $(b).text().trim();
  
    return map.indexOf( aText ) - map.indexOf( bText );
}).appendTo('.dd__list')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="manager">
    <div class="dd__list dd__openTobottom" style="max-height: 160px;">
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Souness</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Smith</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">Advocaat</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dd__option">McLeish</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple but "dirty" method is to empty the container and rebuild the results.
I call it dirty because you need to know the structure and che classes/ids of the generated elements. The following answer only works for that specific use-case, but it can be expanded if needed.

```
var ordered = ["Smith", "Advocaat", "Souness", "McLeish"];

var parent = $("#listParent").empty();

for(var i=0; i<ordered.length; ++i) {
    var cont = $(document.createElement("div")).appendTo(parent);
  $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("dd_option").text(ordered[i]).appendTo(cont);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkc5m8wz/

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use this Code.

$('.manager').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$this.append($this.find('.dd__option').get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('index') - $(b).data('index');
 }));
});

HTML:
<div class="manager">
<div class="dd__list dd__openTobottom" style="max-height: 160px;">
    <div>
        <div class="dd__option" data-index="3" >Souness</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="dd__option" data-index="1">Smith</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="dd__option" data-index="2">Advocaat</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="dd__option" data-index="4">McLeish</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate if it is useful.